# If $T$ is linear and $\|Tv\| \leq \|v\|$, then $T-\sqrt{2}I$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Problem**
>
> Suppose $V$ is a vector space and $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear map
>   such that $\|Tv\| \leq \|v\|$ for every $v \in V$. Prove that
>   $T-\sqrt{2}I$ is invertible.

The case that $V$ is a finite-dimensional is clear:

If $v \in N(T-\sqrt{2}I)$, then $Tv = \sqrt{2}v$, so $\|Tv\| = \sqrt{2}\|v\| \leq \|v\|$ implies $\|v\|=0$.

My question is, does this result remain true in the **infinite dimensional** case? That is to prove the surjectivity of $T-\sqrt{2}I$.

Comment: The statement is still true, but I don't see what this has to do with the surjectivity of $T$, which doesn't necessarily hold even in the finite-dimensional case.

Comment: @MichaelLee A map $T$ to be invertible must be both injective and surjective. In the finite dimensional case injectivity immediately implies surjectivily, by counting the dimensions of the image and the domain. But in the infinite dimensional case there are injective linear operators that are not invertible, for instance $T(x_1,x_2,\ldots, ) = (0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$

Comment: Right, but the invertibility of $T-\sqrt{2}I$ says nothing directly about the invertibility of $T$.

Comment: @MichaelLee Oh I thought we were talking about $T-\sqrt{2}I$, which I had thought the OP also said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $S$ is any linear operator on some Banach space (i.e. a *complete* normed vector space) with $\|S\| < 1$ (from which it follows that $\|Sv\| < \|v\|$ for all $v$), then there is a fairly standard argument that $I-S$ is invertible.  The basic idea is to look at the power series expansion of $(1-s)^{-1}$ (where $s$ is a real or complex variable), but substitute $S$ for $s$ and show that the same argument works.  This standard argument is sketched below:

Note that if $|s| < 1$, then
$$ \frac{1}{1-s} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} s^j. $$
It is this series that we are going to show does the job in a more general space.  That is, this series should give the inverse of $I-S$ in a Banach space.  Indeed, observe that if $\|S\| < 1$, then the series
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} S^j $$
is Cauchy, and so by completeness converges to some operator (note that we really do require a Banach space here, and not just any old normed vector space).  But then
$$ (I-S) \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} S^j \right)
= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (S^j - S^{j+1})
= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} S^j - \sum_{j=0} S^{j+1}
= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} S^j - \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} S^{j} - I\right)
= I.
$$
Multiplication by $(I-S)$ on the other side gives the same result, from which it follows that
$$ (I-S)^{-1} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} S^j. $$
In particular, $I-S$ is invertible whenever $\|S\|<1$.

---

In the case of the original question, assume that $\|T\| \le 1$ and define $S := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} T$.  Since $\|T\| \le 1$, it follows that
$$ \|S\|
= \left\| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} T \right\|
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \|T\|
\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
< 1. $$
Therefore we may apply the result at the top and conclude that $I-S$ is invertible, with inverse given by
$$ (I-S)^{-1} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} S^j. $$
But then
$$ I
= (I-S) \sum_{j=0}^{S^j}
= \left[ \sqrt{2}(I-S) \right] \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} S^j \right]
= (\sqrt{2}I - T) \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{S^j}{\sqrt{2}},
$$
from which it is possible to conclude that $\sqrt{2}I - T$ is invertible, with inverse given by the series above.

Comment: The question states that $\|Tv\| \leq \|v\|$ for all $v$, which implies $\|T\| \leq 1$ (note the non-strictness of the inequality). This is sufficient, since then $\|S\|={1\over \sqrt 2}\|T\| \leq {1\over \sqrt 2} < 1$.

Comment: @lisyarus fix'd

Comment: I also fixed the very first sentence. Please, check that I didn't mess everything up.

Comment: @lisyarus The $T$ in the first paragraph is different from the $T$ in the original problem.  I'll edit to reflect this fact.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you.

Comment: @lisyarus No, thank you for keeping me honest.  I think it reads better now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to solve $(T-\sqrt{2}I)x=y$ for $x$, then would have
$$
                  x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}Tx-y \\
                    = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}T(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}Tx-y)-y \\
                    = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}T)^2 x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}Ty-y \\
                    = ... = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}T)^{N+1}x-\sum_{n=0}^{N}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}T)^ny
$$
Because of the assumptions on $T$, if $x$ were a known solution, it would have to be true that the following series would converge in the norm of the vector space:
$$
        x = -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}T)^ny.
$$
So, knowing $(T-\sqrt{2}I)x=y$ forces the right side to converge in norm to $x$, and the solution is seen to be uniquely given by the sum. Conversely, if the sum converges, then the assumptions on $T$ force the above to hold in the limit. But there is no guarantee that the sum will convergen in general. It must if $x$ is a known solution. However if the space is *complete*, meaning that norm Cauchy sequences converge in the space to a vector, then $(T-\sqrt{2}I)x=y$ has a unique solution $x$ for every $y$ that is given by the infinite sum, which is forced to converge by completeness.